# How to pass text from one Activity to Another with Same Characteristics?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can any one tell me how to pass the value from one screen to its previous screen. Consider the case.i m having two screen first screen with one Textview and button and the second activity have one edittext and button.

If i click the first button then it has to move to second activity and here user has to type something in the textbox. If he press the button from the second screen then the values from the textbox should move to the first activity and that should be displayed in the first activity textview.

This is **passing Values from one activity to another**

i want to pass the text with same FontStyle, Color and Size of the font.

Comment: intent.putExtra("yourString");

Comment: putExtra and getExra are two methods to do this, but if you want to more specific answer then post your code, which you are coded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same style,color and size for first activity TextView and second Activity's EditTextView.

If you are done it with programming, then just pass the other parameters also with the intents, and set it in the first activity's TextView.

Like,

```
intent.putExtra("fontStyle","American Dream");
intent.putExtra("color","value");
intent.putExtra("size","value");
```

Use this in first activity to set TextView's properties.

```
String fontStyle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("fontStyle");
String fontColor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("color");
String fontSize  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("size");

  Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/"+fontStyle+".ttf"); 
  // here fontStyle is string which you passed from the second Activity 
  textView.setTypeface(font2);
```

Comment: passing font and getting same value in first activity ok, getting font from assets popup force close error.                                     code is : String MyText = i.getStringExtra("text_font");           Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                                                          "fonts/s");

Comment: and if you found this is helpful to you, please vote up it. and mark as correct answer.

Comment: see my code:in FaAct. String f = "American Dream";
          i.putExtra("font",f);                                    in secondAct.String fontStyle = i.getStringExtra("font");/*Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),                                       "fonts/" + fontStyle ); System.out.println("font2 value is" + font2);*/
        //tv.setTypeface(font2); it's getting force close

Comment: FATAL EXCEOTION and 08-17 19:13:46.432: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.text/com.example.text.TextActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: already i done this it' getting correct , by using in this  Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),                                                 "fonts/"+temp+".ttf"); for this not working.

Comment: debug the program, put break point at tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view); line in textActivity and inspect intent i, also inspect font_style variable and look what values it have and type of it..

Comment: welcome. and if this is correct then please upvote the answer.

Comment: i was selected this as answer for up vote i require 10 more reputations, i will vote not now!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do this onClick

```
SecondButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

                            text.settext(Edittext.getText());
            Intent intent= new Intent(form2.this, form1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```